# Turn a sync function into an awaitable function

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

I've got a situation where I can't be sure if a function will be sync, or async. In other words, the function has a type signature of `Union[Callable[..., Awaitable[Any]], Callable[..., Any]]`.

I can't seem to find a good (non-deprecated) way of turning the above type signature into a consistent type of `Callable[..., Awaitable[Any]]`.

The only way I was able to find how to do this, is by doing this:

```py
import asyncio
import inspect
from typing import Any, Awaitable, Callable, List, Union

def force_awaitable(function: Union[Callable[..., Awaitable[Any]], Callable[..., Any]]) -> Callable[..., Awaitable[Any]]:
    if inspect.isawaitable(function):
        # Already awaitable
        return function
    else:
        # Make it awaitable
        return asyncio.coroutine(function)
```

However, `asyncio.coroutine` (which is normally used as a decorator) is deprecated since Python 3.8. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.coroutine

The alternative provided does not work for me here, since I don't use `asyncio.coroutine` as a decorator. Unlike a decorator, the `async` keyword can't be used as a function.

How do I turn a sync function (not awaitable) into an async function (awaitable)?

### Other considered options

Above I've shown that you can detect if something is awaitable. This allows us to change how to call like so:

```py
def my_function():
    pass

if inspect.isawaitable(function):
    await my_function()
else:
    my_function()
```

However, this feels clunky, can create messy code, and creates unnecessary checks inside big loops. I want to be able to define how to call the function before I'm entering my loop.

---

In NodeJS I would simply await the sync function:

```js
// Note: Not Python!
function sync() {}
await sync();
```

When I try to do the same thing in Python, I'm greeted with an error:

```py
def sync():
  pass
await sync() # AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute '__await__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an `async` function with the original `function` object in its scope:

```
def to_coroutine(f:Callable[..., Any]):
   async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      return f(*args, **kwargs)
   return wrapper

def force_awaitable(function: Union[Callable[..., Awaitable[Any]], Callable[..., Any]]) -> Callable[..., Awaitable[Any]]:
   if inspect.iscoroutinefunction(function):
      return function
   else:
      return to_coroutine(function)
```

Now, if `function` is not `await`able, `force_awaitable` will return a coroutine function that contains `function`.

---

```
def test_sync(*args, **kwargs):
   pass

async def main():
   await force_awaitable(test_sync)('foo', 'bar')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not help. It will turn the function into a `coroutine object` instead of a `coroutine function`. Which means that you can't do: `await force_awaitable(my_function)("bar", "baz") # TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable`

Comment: @Lakitna Ah, I understand, please see my recent edit.

Comment: Yeah! Oh man, I've looked so long for this one. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Lakitna Glad to help!

Comment: Small change for posterity: `inspect.isawaitable` should be `inspect.iscoroutinefunction`. This makes it work for methods as well as functions.

Comment: @Lakitna Thank you, please see my recent edit